# Endtime for machine in cumulatives

Tags: prolog, clpfd, sicstus-prolog

I'm working on a scheduling problem which I have used `cumulatives/3` to model.

Ex:

```
s1(Ss, Es, Ms ) :-
    Ss = [S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7],
    Es = [E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7],
    Ms = [M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7],

    domain(Ss, 1, 30),
    domain(Es, 1, 30),
    domain(Ms, 1, 3),

    %task( StartTime, Duration, EndTime, ResourceCons, MachineId)
    Tasks = [
        task(S1, 6,E1, 1,M1),
        task(S2, 6,E2, 1,M2),
        task(S3, 3,E3, 1,M3),
        task(S4, 7,E4, 1,M4),
        task(S5, 5,E5, 1,M5),
        task(S6, 8,E6, 1,M6),
        task(S7, 4,E7, 1,M7)
    ],

    %machine( Id, ResourceBound ),
    Machines = [
        machine( 1, 1),
        machine( 2, 1),
        machine( 3, 1)
    ],

    cumulatives(Tasks, Machines, [bound(upper)] ),
    append([Ss,Es,Ms], Vars),
    labeling([], Vars).
```

If I run the predicate `s1/3` I get:

```
| ?- s1(Ss, Es, Ms ).
Es = [7,7,4,11,12,15,15],
Ms = [1,2,3,3,1,2,3],
Ss = [1,1,1,4,7,7,11] ? 
yes
| ?-
```

This example shows that m1 is done at 12, m2 at 15, and m3 at 15.

But what is the 'optimal' or best way to express when each machine is done with all its tasks? I would like to add some additional constraints to the end-time for a machine.
Is there any global constraints which fits well to express this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of expressing it.  The only relevant global constraint that comes to mind is maximum/2.

```
| ?- makespans([1,2,3,3,1,2,3], [7,7,4,11,12,15,15], [M1,M2,M3]).
M1 = 12,
M2 = 15,
M3 = 15 ? 

% makespans(+Machines, +EndTimes, +MakeSpans) :-
%   given N tasks assigned to Machines and finishing at EndTimes,
%   the ith element of MakeSpans is unified with the max finish time for task i
%   MakeSpans should be a list of the right length
makespans(Machines, EndTimes, MakeSpans) :-
(   foreach(Make,MakeSpans),
    count(I,1,_),
    param(Machines,EndTimes)
do  (   foreach(E,EndTimes),
    foreach(M,Machines),
    foreach(T,Terms),
    param(I)
    do  T #= (M#=I)*E
    ),
    maximum(Make, Terms)
).
```